# Python/Discord: Bot doesn't have attribute add roles

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

this is the code with the error:

```
if message.content == "Test":
    member = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id="Character Created")
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)
```

This is my imports ("bot" used to be defined as Discord.Client() but I swapped it for the bot import):

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext.commands import bot
```

This is the error message:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\idlerpgtest.py", line 41, in on_message
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands.bot' has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work because `bot` has no attribute `add_roles`, `discord.Member` has. So you can do this:

```
if message.content == "Test":
    member = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id="Character Created")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: If someone answers your question and it works for you, you should accept it as an answer so if someone encounters this problem or error, (s)he can find his/her answer easily.